# Problem with dom_import_simplexml on newly created SimpleXML nodes

Tags: php, simplexml

I'm working on a class extending `SimpleXMLElement`:

```
class MyXML extends SimpleXMLElement {
    public function cdata($text) {
        $node = dom_import_simplexml($this);
        $owner = $node->ownerDocument;
        $node->appendChild($owner->createCDATASection($text));
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Since it's an `SimpleXMLElement`, I can dynamically create XML nodes inside it:

```
$xml = new MyXML('<foo/>');
$xml->bar = 'Test';
print $xml->asXML(); // <foo><bar>Test</bar></foo>
```

But when I try to run this:

```
$xml = new MyXML('<foo/>');
$xml->bar->cdata('Test');
```

I get:

```
Warning: dom_import_simplexml(): Invalid Nodetype to import in [..]
```

However, if I force the `SimpleXMLElement` node to be created before running `cdata()`, it works again:

```
$xml = new MyXML('<foo/>');
$xml->bar = '';
$xml->bar->cdata('Test');
print $xml->asXML(); // <foo><bar><![CDATA[Test]]></bar></foo>
```

I'm curious if what I found is a bug, and if there is any way to work around it without "priming" the node first.

Comment: Well, I can certainly reproduce it, and calling `$this->asXML()` inside `cdata()` will yield false, and `$this->getName()` an empty string. Seems the node is not 'finished'  at that time, namely the link to the parent element. For instance, the built-in method `$xml->foo->addAttribute('a','b');` would also fail. More a (very reasonable) feature request then an actual bug IMHO.

Comment: Thank you, with `$this->getName()` I can at least detect the problematic situation.